# Selecting a 'property value' from an array based on another 'property value' in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this.

```
var nodes = [{ID:"101", x:100, y:200}
        ,{ID:"102", x:200, y:200}
        ,{ID:"103", x:300, y:300}
        ,{ID:"104", x:200, y:300}];
```

I'd like to have a function which takes node's ID as input and return its (x,y).
For example, the function `coordinates(103)`should read the array (nodes) and return x = 300, y = 300 when it's called. Any pointer is appreciated. Thanks :)
 This is what I have so far. It works but I'd like to know neater and tidier methods.

```
function coordinates(id){
    for (var i=0 in nodes){
        if(nodes[i].ID == id){
            return { x: nodes[i].x, y: nodes[i].y};
        }
    }
}
console.log(coordinates(102));
```

Comment: ok, let us work this out together. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically you're looking at something like this

```
var f = function(id){
    var match = nodes.filter(function(d){ 
        return d.ID === id; 
    })
    return match && match.length && {x: match[0].x, y:match[0].y} 
    || {x: undefined, y: undefined};
};
```

then `f('101')` outputs `{x: 100, y:200}` and if cannot find a match then it will output `{x: undefined, y: undefined}`

Answer (score 2):

See comments inline:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1y7b5mxu/)

```js
var nodes = [{
  ID: "101",
  x: 100,
  y: 200
}, {
  ID: "102",
  x: 200,
  y: 200
}, {
  ID: "103",
  x: 300,
  y: 300
}, {
  ID: "104",
  x: 200,
  y: 300
}];

var noOfCord = nodes.length;

var coordinates = function(id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < noOfCord; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].ID == id) {
      return {
        x: nodes[i].x,
        y: nodes[i].y
      };
    }
  }
}


document.write(coordinates(103).x + ', ' + coordinates(103).y);
```

Comment: I like your custom approach :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), like so

```js
var nodes = [{
    ID: "101",
    x: 100,
    y: 200
}, {
    ID: "102",
    x: 200,
    y: 200
}, {
    ID: "103",
    x: 300,
    y: 300
}, {
    ID: "104",
    x: 200,
    y: 300
}];

function coordinates(nodes, id) {
  var result = nodes.filter(function (el) {
      return +el.ID === id;    
  });
  
  if (result && result.length) {
    result = result[0];

    return {
       x: result.x,
       y: result.y
    };
  }
  
  return null;
}

console.log(coordinates(nodes, 103));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using array [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter), Try:

```js
function coordinates(id){
  return nodes.filter(function(e){ return e.ID == id })[0]
}

var nodes=[{ID:"101",x:100,y:200},{ID:"102",x:200,y:200},{ID:"103",x:300,y:300},{ID:"104",x:200,y:300}];

var result = coordinates("103");

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result, null, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant solutions with concrete JavaScript have already been proposed by people here. So I propose another alternative using *underscore.js*, just in case you're curious.

```
function coordinates(id){
    var n = _.findWhere(nodes, {ID: id});
    return {x: n.x, y: n.y }
}
```